# How to remove non-repeated items from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples (which is sorted based on the first element of tuples) and what I desire now is to remove items that have no more than one occurrence? I guess there's no pythonic way of doing this. BTW I appreciate any idea on this.

Comment: Please add a [MRE] to your question.

Comment: Loop through your list, for each tuple count occurences in the list, if more than one time, you add to a new list to hold the result. Once done the new list would contain the multi occurring tuples. Now you can convert to set and then convert back to list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is not a code-writing service. You are expected to make some attempt to solve the problem yourself first, even if it's just [trying to find a solution elsewhere or looking elsewhere to try to understand the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Ideally you will end up with some sort of code, which you should show to us, along with a clear explanation of why and how it fails to solve the problem.

Comment: the best way to deal with my case was as @RobPy suggested. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `collections.Counter` to find the number of occurrences and then only keep those that occur more than once:

```
from collections import Counter
items = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
count = Counter(items)
repeated = [key for key, value in count.items() if value > 1]
```

Comment: tweaked this a little and it worked out. but since I had some sort of complex data structure and had to use for loop for my case. thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on the list without needing to count the elements:

```
l = [(1,2), (3,4), (3,4), (3,5), (3,5), (3,5), (5,6), (5,7), (5,8), (5,8)]
i = 0
l2 = []
while i < len(l):
    tmp = l[i]
    found_more_than_once = False
    while i+1 < len(l) and l[i+1] == tmp:
        i += 1
        l2.append(l[i])
        found_more_than_once = True
    if found_more_than_once:
        l2.append(l[i])
    i += 1

print(l2)
```

Comment: What makes you think it's O(n²)? `collections.Counter` is linear in time and so is the list comprehension.  Btw, it'd be more pythonic to use `for` loops and `enumerate` instead of `while` and counter variables.

Comment: I used while loop to be able to increment the counter on certain conditions within the nested loop. Regarding the complexity, sorry I didn't notice that you used `collections.Counter`.

Comment: I ran some profiling on it (500 items in the list, 10,000 iterations , and the `Counter` version ran in 14% of the time required by this version.

Comment: although my list of tuples was sorted but decided to drop the while loop part. by the way I used some hard-coded solution as your suggestion. thanks